# Linearizing product of binary variables

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, binary-programming

How would I linearize the following expression

$$ z = (1-x)y $$

where $x,y \in \{0,1\}$? Ideally, I would want to formulate this as a system of linear inequalities.

Comment: $x,y \in [0,1]$ ?! but you said binary variables, you mean $x,y \in \{0,1\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, just made the correction.

Comment: It isn't possible to write $\overline{X}Y$ as a boolean sum such as $X+Y$ or $\overline{X}+Y$ or $X+\overline{Y}$...

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-variable+linearization

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables

Answer (score 2):

$(1-x)$ is just swapping $0$ and $1$. so without changing the problem consider $\bar{x}=1-x$ as our binary variable.
$$
z = \bar{x}y \qquad \bar{x},y \in \{0,1\}
$$
so logically this means:
$$
z \equiv \bar{x} \land y. \tag{1}
$$
$\bar{x}$ and $y$ are our independent variables so (1) chronologically means :
$$
\bar{x}=0 \lor y=0 \Rightarrow z=0 \\
\bar{x}=1 \land y=1 \Rightarrow z=1
$$
you can linearize these by introducing binary variable $\gamma$ with additional three constraints:
$$
z = \gamma \\
\gamma \leq \bar{x} \\
\gamma \leq y \\
\bar{x}+y \leq \gamma +1 .
$$
you can easily check that this works. if for example $\bar{x}=0$ then by second constraint $\gamma=0$. third and fourth constraint become redundant. (also similar for $y=0$). and of $\bar{x}=y=1$ then by fourth constraint $\gamma=1$.

Comment: No need to introduce $\gamma$.  If you do, you can relax $\gamma \in\{0,1\}$ to $\gamma \ge 0$.